# CentOS 7 and pam_mysql for SSH Authentication

Tags: centos7

I'm preparing my CentOS 6 server for upgrading to CentOS 7 and wondered where pam_mysql (from EPEL) was gone (yum search - no find).
Then I heard about SSSD which sounds really good, but found it only in connection with LDAP - which I'd love to use but simply can't because I've got an admin panel (froxlor) running, 
which stores user data in a mysql-db (which is also the backend for proftpd w/mod_sql and libnss-mysql), and want to have SSH Login for the users, I need to have SSH Authentication via mysql.

libnss-mysql is already working - but I can't login via SSH.

How'd one accomplish this in CentOS 7 since pam_mysql is gone?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [project](http://pam-mysql.sourceforge.net/) appears to be dead, with the last update in 2006. Naturally, it has been removed from EPEL because of this.

However, there is a fork at https://github.com/NigelCunningham/pam-MySQL. Maybe try this, but I would be wary to use such an important module from outside of a standard repo.

Maybe you could suggest this fork as replacement to the EPEL people.

Comment: Thanks! I came across this fork, but on a production server like mine it's not a good feeling to have a one-person-project running such important service, if you understand what I mean...
I guess I'm one of very few people actually asking for system-auth agains mysql, but anyhow I can't imagine that since it's a neat feature if one doesn't want to maintain a whole LDAP directory just for user+pw and I don't see a reason why it's been "deprecated".

I'm just wondering how other people accomplish that!? They just don't ?

Comment: I could have LDAP with mysqldb as backend, but that's ridiculous, isn't it? :D

Comment: This is a reason to drop your admin panel. Also, using MySQL as an passdb backend is no more or less an overkill than using LDAP, with the distinction that LDAP is a standard approach that is widely supported.

Comment: I thought about dropping it about 100 times and everytime I came to conclusion that I can't for now. Mysql is anyway active because of websites, so a table for user data which has to be there is no overkill. So, I can assume that NOBODY is actually using mysql as auth-backend for PAM anymore? That brings me to the point where I really think of putting the mysqldb behind LDAP -.-

Comment: If you do that, you have to be aware that you will need another database with its own schema and it's very unlikely that you can reuse your current database at all for this. The MySQL schema for OpenLDAP is very special and not-straightforward from a "normal" SQL perspective, as it has to map the LDAP tree into flat tables. All this makes the LDAP setup significantly more complex.

Comment: understand. then I should think of writing a script to query the needed data from mysql and put it into the LDAP directory. Again. Ridiculous ^^ but thanks for your answers anyway! At least I know that supposingly no-one is using pam with mysql anymore.

Comment: the simplest thing would have been to find a way to connect mysql with SSSD. kind of a plugin ... pity :)

Answer (score 3):

While using a Fedora RPM might be ok for the most part, should you want to build your own RPM for Centos 7, based on the [Fedora source RPM](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/26/dist/100/size/348712/name/pam_mysql-0.7-0.20.rc1.fc23.src.rpm), this is the steps:

```
# Install required build packages
yum install make gcc-c++ autoconf automake libtool rpm-build pam-devel mysql-devel openssl-devel

# Download the fedora source rpm
wget "ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/archive.fedoraproject.org/fedora-secondary/releases/23/Everything/source/SRPMS/p/pam_mysql-0.7-0.20.rc1.fc23.src.rpm"

# Rebuild the RPM, it should say "Wrote blah blah.rpm" at the end
rpmbuild --rebuild pam_mysql-0.7-0.20.rc1.fc23.src.rpm

# Install the Centos Specific RPM
yum localinstall /home/you/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/pam_mysql-0.7-0.20.rc1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
```

Of course you should be using your Centos 7 server to do this rebuild.

For any future Centos 7 setups now that you have a compatible RPM you can put it on your own Yum server or just a webserver/s3 bucket and install via a custom URL:

```
yum localinstall http://www.example.com/path/to/pam_mysql-0.7-0.20.rc1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 2):

I just configured a new CentOS 7 box and wanted to use mysql with vsftpd.
I tried Cristian's suggestion and searched for:
pam_mysql-0.7-0.16.rc1.fc20.x86_64.rpm

Which I found here with a list of mirrors:
http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/25165183/dir/fedora_20/com/pam_mysql-0.7-0.16.rc1.fc20.x86_64.rpm.html

I've tested it with vsftp and everything is fine.

Comment: Hi, I see you've successfully got pam_mysql to work. I'm facing a couple minor issues. I'm wondering if you could take a peak at my question posted on serverfault and maybe help me out. Thanks http://serverfault.com/questions/663721/pam-mysql-missing-in-centos-7

Answer (score 0):

More people than you think have this problem. I don't see any reason to not use pam_mysql.
Try to use pam_mysql-0.7-0.15.rc1.fc19.x86_64.rpm (or pam_mysql-0.7-0.16.rc1.fc20.x86_64.rpm) from Fedora Everything. Check libnss-mysql version (libnss-mysql-1.5-20.fc20.x86_64.rpm, libnss-mysql-1.5-19.fc19.x86_64.rpm libnss-mysql-1.5-19.el7.x86_64.rpm). Seems to work, but test it first.